# Clique cover number and independence number

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a graph $G$ on $n$ vertices. Is it true that if the clique cover number of $G$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{3n}{4}$, then the independence number of $G$ is greater than or equal to $\frac{n}{2}$? In other words, does $\chi(\bar{G})\geq \frac{3n}{4}$ imply $\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n}{2}$?

I believe the statement is true (as I haven't been able to come up with any counterexamples), but how can one prove it if it's true? If not, what would be a counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intuition:
If there are $a_1$ single vertex clique and $a_2$ two vertex clique corresponding to clique cover number then:
$$3(3n/4-a_1-a_2)+2a_2+a_1 \leq n$$
$$9n/4-2a_1-a_2 \leq n$$
$$5n/4\leq 2a_1+a_2$$

So you have that atleast $2a_1 \geq 5n/4-a_2$ and we have $a_2 \leq n/2$ $ \implies a_1 \geq 5n/8-n/4 = 3n/8$. So your graph with clique  cover number of $3n/4$ has atleast $3n/8$ singleton cliques. Sounds like a sparse graph.

Infact this shows $\alpha(G) \geq a_1 \geq 3n/8$. Very close to what you wanted.
This is because if there are edges between these $a_1$ vertices then this would introduce a clique of size $2$ and would reduce the number of cliques.